# Apply recurrence to an appointment on code behind (DevExpress Scheduler Control)

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I am using the [devExpress scheduler control](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument8679). Note what I am trying to achieve on the following code is to add a recurance to an appointment on code behind. In this example I am doing that when I create a new appointment.

**My window consists of a scheduler Control:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:dxsch="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/scheduler">

    <dxsch:SchedulerControl Name="schedulerControl1" />

</Window>
```

**And code behind consists of:**

```
using System.Windows;
using DevExpress.XtraScheduler;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() // Constructor
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Fires when window loads
        {
            schedulerControl1.Storage.AppointmentsInserted += new PersistentObjectsEventHandler(Storage_AppointmentsInserted);
        }

        void Storage_AppointmentsInserted(object sender, PersistentObjectsEventArgs e) // fires when a new appointment is added
        {
            Appointment addedAppointment = null;
            foreach (Appointment item in e.Objects)
                addedAppointment = item;

            /*
                I want to set the reinsurance info in here!
                I cant because RecuranceInfo = null!                  
            */
            addedAppointment.RecurrenceInfo.Type = RecurrenceType.Hourly; // <- App Crashes
        }               
    }
}
```

I do not want to bind the recurrence property of the control.

**In other words** It will be great if I could create an appointment that starts at 2PM today and repeats daily with no end date. How could I be able to create that appointment on code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is in this link:  http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument6201

basically I had to do:

```
        Appointment apt = schedulerControl1.Storage.CreateAppointment(AppointmentType.Pattern);
        apt.Start = DateTime.Now;
        apt.End = apt.Start.AddHours(2);
        apt.Subject = "My Subject";
        apt.Location = "My Location";
        apt.Description = "My Description";

        apt.RecurrenceInfo.Type = RecurrenceType.Daily;

        schedulerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.Add(apt);
```